# two menus show different menu based on what menuitem is selected on menu1

Tags: menus

Iv got two menus:
menu1 with three menuitems.
menu2 which is based on which menuitem I selected in menu1

Like this:

**menu1** menu2 menu3
**Home** Tax Company Aboutus

menu1 **menu2** menu3
**Home** Posts News et

menu1 menu2 **menu3**
**Home** Test1 Test2 et

How can I make this?
Thanks

Comment: I have seen similar questions. Have you searched the site?

Answer (score 1):

You could create just one menu in wordpress backoffice, and menu 2 would be a submenu of each item, like this:

- menu 1

  - Home
  - Tax
  - Company
  - About us
- menu 2

  - Home
  - Posts
  - News
- menu 3

  - Home
  - Test 1
  - Test 2

Then you could use some jquery and css to show each submenu according to what you choose.